# Default google maps marker InfoWindow background resource

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

I want to create InfoWindow with custom margins. It's possible when I override getInfoWindow() from InfoWindowAdapter, but I have to maintain tooltip background by myself. I'd like to use original, default background. 
Where this .xml/9-path resource can be found?

Comment: "Where this .xml/9-path resource can be found?" -- on some Google developer's hard drive, if it exists at all. The Play Services SDK is not open source. The Play Services Framework itself is also not open source. It is unclear where the info window frame is, or whether it is even a resource (versus generated in Java code). And, you don't have the rights to use it.

Comment: @CommonsWare, that's sad. Thank you!